# Is this code vulnerable to DOM based XSS? jquery wrap()

Tags: xss, dom, jquery

Data is read from `window.location` and passed to the `wrap()` function of function of jQuery via the following statement:

```
t.Location.wrap(window.location)
```

The version of jQuery in use is the 1.12.1 - Is this code vulnerable to DOM based XSS?

Comment: Difficult to tell when we don't know what `t.Location` is. Would you be willing to add more context and detail to your question?

Comment: try it with a script tag. if it calls `.html()` internally, it's likely vulnerable.